# How to divide a long number into several numbers in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to divide a number into several based on given counter value.....

```
if my Number is 12345 and counter value 2. then I need 12,13,14,15,23,24,25,34,35,45...

if counter value 3 then I need 123, 134, 145, 234, 245, 345...
```

Thanks In advance...

Comment: Have you tried searching google? There's tons of similar questions

Comment: I don't really get the quention?

Comment: a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for p in itertools.chain(itertools.combinations(a, 2):
     print p